# Can pip install from setup.cfg, as if installing from a requirements file?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

According to the [`setuptools` documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files), `setuptools` version 30.3.0 (December 8, 2016) "allows using configuration files (usually *setup.cfg*) to define package’s metadata and other options which are normally supplied to `setup()` function". Similar to running `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install Python packages from a requirements file, is there a way to ask `pip` to install the packages listed in the `install_requires` option of a `setup.cfg` configuration file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, pip does not currently have facilities for parsing requirements from `setup.cfg`.  It will only install dependencies along with the main package(s) provided in `setup.py`.

Comment: Or, maybe you just want the requirements to be installed, but not the actual package?  AFAIK, pip doesn't have the ability to read `setup.cfg` itself, all of the options are read in to `setup.py` by `setuptools.config.read_configuration`.

Comment: The comment by @rnorris is correct. I don't want to install the Python package itself, I want to install its dependencies. I want something like `pip install -r requirements.txt`, but something like `pip install -r setup.cfg`.

Comment: Pip itself does not support that.  You will probably need to roll your own solution.  Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish by installing the dependencies of a particular module, but not the module itself?

Comment: Installing the dependencies in a virtual environment in order to develop the project itself (without necessarily installing it).

Comment: @argentpepper I would like to have it also. Any solution to that one by now? Thank you.

Comment: I think for the use case argentpepper mentions, `pip install --editable .` would be an appropriate solution.  The intended use case of the `--editable` flag is to make the development package available in the install environment and have any source changes show up without having to re-install the package.

Answer (score 32):

If you have all your dependencies and other metadata defined in `setup.cfg`, just create a minimal `setup.py` file in the same directory that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

From now on you can run `pip install` and it will install all the dependencies defined in `setup.cfg` as if they were declared in `setup.py`.

Comment: Works like a charm, as documented [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files).

Comment: for reference `pip install .` from the same directory as setup.py

Comment: Now it is even possible to accompany `setup.cfg` by empty `pyproject.toml` instead of the minimal `setup.py` to allow `pip install`. (pip 21.3.1, Python 3.8.10)

Comment: As of March 2022, with `setuptools>=61`, one can ditch `setup.cfg` in favor of `pyproject.toml` ([docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/pyproject_config.html)).  `setuptools` is still working on letting one ditch the placeholder `setup.py` file in favor of just a `pyproject.toml`

Comment: It does not work for me: `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")` MacOS 12.6.2 Chipset M1 - Python 3.10.9

Answer (score 15):

If your `setup.cfg` belongs to a well-formed package, you can do e.g.:

```
pip install -e .[tests,dev]
```

(install this package in place, with given extras)

afterwards you can `pip uninstall` that package by name, leaving deps in place.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks - I'm using `packages = find` in my project, and `pip install -e .` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my workaround. I use the following command to parse the `install_requires` element from the `setup.cfg` file and install the packages using `pip`.

```
python3 -c "import configparser; c = configparser.ConfigParser(); c.read('setup.cfg'); print(c['options']['install_requires'])" | xargs pip install
```

Here is a more readable version of the Python script before the pipe in the above command line.

```
import configparser
c = configparser.ConfigParser()
c.read('setup.cfg')
print(c['options']['install_requires'])
```

Comment: This script as-is does not support packages that must be installed via `dependency_links`.