# If I have already listed all my requirements in setup.cfg, do I still need a requirements.txt?

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

I am preparing a python package for distribution. Currently it only has `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` files (with no `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`). Inside `setup.cfg` I have `install_requires`

`setup.cfg`:

```
...
[options]
...
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires=
    requests>=2
    numpy>=1.13
    matplotlib>=2
    .
    .
    .
...
```

Now, do I still need to provide a `requirements.txt` with specific versions of dependencies and sub-dependencies? Even if it is not strictly needed, are there any benefits to doing so?

---

My thoughts currently:

When I use don't have a `requirements.txt`, it automatically installs the latest version of the required packages which are available in that version of pip. And my package is installing and running in the limited number of environments I tested.

I understand that putting specific version numbers for dependencies can lightly guard against any breaking changes made by a dependency.

On the other hand, dependencies may stop supporting a specific version of python. So if I generate `requirements.txt` in `python 3.8`, the specific version of that dependency may not be available in `python 3.6`.

Comment: requirement.txt and install_requires quite have different purpose. check it out this link this may help [--->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py)

Comment: @abhipatil Thank you. Since I am just the developer here, I shouldn't bother with `requirements.txt`. I wonder why so many packaging tutorials talk about `requirements.txt`. Should have just stuck to the Official packaging guidelines.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/ cleared all my doubts about the purposes of the various files

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43658870, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46205648